# Create Object or Blob from a specified url

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I need to have a blob or any other object forms like arraybuffer so I can display a file (like image,video) in the web-app I've been making.(the web-app is built with only Javascript and html5)

The blob/objects will be stored locally inside the browser with IndexedDB or any other possible method, so that anytime when I open the web, I don't have to download the whole image/video from the specified URL,

For example, I need to display certain images/videos from these url:

- www.abcde.com/BBC.jpg
- gamedomain/content/orphan.mp4
- www.abc.net/content.png

usually, the image/video will be displayed using img or video tag in HTML5 respectively,
but now I want to have those content stored as blob or arraybuffer,

How can I do that?